# multicols - different column widths

Tags: multicol

How can I set the width of the 1st column to 70%, and the width of the 2nd column to 30% of the pagewidth?

```
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    text in column 1
    \columnbreak
    text in column 2
\end{multicols}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: There are no options for such things. You can use the tabularx-environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just after a two-column document with varying column width, I would suggest to take a look at the [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/flowfram) package which allows to customize column layout and width. I used it for statistical handouts with text on a `.7\textwidth` column, and illustration on the remaining spaces (before discovering Tufte class), but I think it should not be too difficult to use it for two-column document with text only.